# Drawing the graph of $x=i^2y$. Where was I wrong?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

> I was asked to draw the graph of $x=i^2y$ where $i$=iota in an interview.

So, I sketched it as a normal $\ x+y=0\ $ line in the $x$-$y$ graph. But, the interviewer said it was wrong.

He further said that the flaw in my graph is that: at the point $(0,0)$ which is the origin it is broken, meaning that the "line" (requested set of points) will not cross through the origin.

Namely, it should be like {$x+y=0$ minus the origin point} . However, he didn't tell me the reason.

> So, my doubt is that why is it so? Why it is not defined at origin?

Comment: I would be curious to hear for his reasons too... I totally agree with you, are you sure there wasn't stuff written in small characters in the statement ?

Comment: @zwim So, you mean that it is not so? But, he was a faculty from a very well reputed institution interviewing students for the scholarship purpose.

Comment: @zwim No, he just told me to draw it on the blackboard. The question was written there only and I had looked it for a few minutes to make sure that whatever I draw is correct and that I cannot get into the question trap.

Comment: @jayant98, I do not see anything wrong with your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the equation.

Comment: @user247327 What do you mean it does not pass through the origin? Clearly the point $(x,y)=(0,0)$ satisfies $x+y=0$.

Comment: The imaginary unit is not usually denoted by iota ( $\iota$ ), but by the roman-style letter $i$ (or sometimes $j$). Does $\iota$ have some special meaning in the field you were interviewing for? Also, if it was intended to be the imaginary unit, then maybe this was a test of your reaction to your superior being incorrect...

Comment: Are you sure you weren't asked to draw the graph of $x/y=i^2$, and "saw" it as asking for the graph of $x=i^2y$?

Comment: @Mark I was interviewed under the syllabus of a senior high school student. So, I am pretty sure that it was iota because otherwise he wouldn't state "where i is iota".

Comment: @Barry Well, I know the difference y can make when y is in the denominator.

Comment: Is the **same** question that you read from the blackboard?

Comment: @manooooh Yes. Sir, you are right. I was asked only 5 questions so I remember them quite clearly. Also after me another student was asked by them the same 3 questions.

Comment: Well, maybe the interviewer had it fixed in *his* head that he was asking about the equation $x/y=i^2$.  Either that or he has an idiosyncratic notion that "iota" can only multiply nonzero numbers.

Comment: Are you agree with the fact $i^2=-1$?

Comment: To be clear, I wasn't saying "it wasn't iota", I'm just saying I haven't seen iota used to denote the imaginary unit. Maybe in your country/region, that's common, but I was wondering if it could have some other meaning

Comment: @jayant98 But stating "where i is iota" is clearly nonsense - the characters for $i$ and $\iota$ look significantly different so that when spoken or handwritten, there is no reason to use one for the other (and again, the imaginary unit is commonly not denoted with $\iota$)

Comment: @Barry So, it means that my graph was correct and that there was not any flaw in it?

Comment: @jayant98, I certainly see no flaw in your graph.  An appropriate question for the interviewer would be, If $i^2y$ doesn't equal $0$ when $y=0$, then what *does* it equal?

Comment: @Hagen I don't know hy he stated it? But, he had stated it while he instructed me to do the question as he read it  and other interviewers were sitting beside him.

Comment: @Hagen looking online, it seems calling the imaginary unit "iota" while still writing $i$ (rather than $\iota$) is somewhat common in India at least. This was confusing to speakers of other dialects like me, but at least I now know it's standard in some places.